# Grant read only access to postgresql schema

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema

I want to grant user `foo_user` read only access to schema `bar_schema`.

I executed the following commands

```
postgres=> GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA bar_schema TO foo_user;
GRANT
postgres=> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA bar_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO foo_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
```

How can I now validate that `foo_user` had indeed RO access to `bar_schema` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user with the appropriate permissions, you can

```
SET ROLE foo_user;
```

to become that role and then try to access the tables.

You forgot the following privilege:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA bar_schema TO foo_user;
```